# Tweepy raises bad authentication data error

Tags: python-2.7, url, twitter, tweepy

I am working on a twitter bot using tweepy. The bot auto-replies to specific users whose tweet handle it receives as input. The bot was working fine for weeks and then suddenly started throwing this 'Bad Authentication Data' or the following to be more precise :

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Bad Authentication data.', 'code': 215}]
```

Apparently the problem is in this particular part of the code :

```
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    ts=api.user_timeline(screen_name=s,count=1)
```

I have entered the correct keys for the twitter application. I read about this problem on blogs where people say that it is an issue with `POSTFIELDS` and that it can be fixed by passing the status as URL in the `api.update_status` function. Is that right? If yes, please give me an example of how it can be done. I'm passing the message and tweet reply id in the update_status function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of Tweepy? Are your other API calls working properly?

Comment: Yes I am using the latest version and all other API calls are working. The problem is with the keys I guess because the problem is about authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote

```
auth.secure = True
```

and it fixed in my case, hope it helps!